# Using an Interpretation, Prove Two Equations Are Not Equivalent

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have been working on this problem for hours and cant seem to understand how to go about doing it. The question is to prove that

[image]

Is not equivalent to

[image]

by giving an interpretation which is a model for one, but not for the other.

I don't see how simply switching the position of the existential quantifier makes a difference. Can someone please give me some pointers? Thank you.

Comment: To see why makes a difference think on the $\delta-\varepsilon$ definition of limit.

Comment: If you think of quantifiers more dynamically it becomes obvious why.

Comment: So we have the difference between "...exists $x$ such that for all $y$..." and "for all $y$ there exists $x$ such that..."  Consider what these statements mean if you pick a specific value for $x$ (for example).  Can you see what effect the order has?  Consider also the synonymous "... for all $y$ ..." and "... for every $y$ ..."

Comment: I am reading the first in English as "for every element w, there exists at least one element x such that for any combination of two other elements y and z, q(w,x,y,z) is true" and similarly for the second. I mentally understand the difference, but I cannot see how to create a relation q to make this matter.

Comment: Complementing abiessu's comment: let $q(w,,x,y,z)$ mean something in which $w$ and $z$ do not occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $g(w,x,y,z)$ hold if $x\lt y$, domain the reals.

Comment: Will mark as answer. Thank you for simplifying the scope of the question. I was confused by assuming that the relation must somehow incorporate all of the variables.

Comment: You can decorate it with mention of $w$ and $z$ if you really want to, by using say $(x\lt y)\land (w=z)$. But you certainly do not need to.